# Display check box on reactive form using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to display Prime NG checkbox in model driven form. However, I can't figure out the exact syntax. According to [Docs](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox). I should add (For simplicity I didn't created a loop)

```
   <p-checkbox [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['selectedValues']"></p-checkbox>
   <p-checkbox [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['selectedValues']"></p-checkbox>
   <p-checkbox [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['selectedValues']"></p-checkbox>
```

But how should I correctly implemented it? Currently my idea is to create an object FormObject selectedValues as a FormArray should be inside and I should call that object in checkbox.

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  signInForm: FormGroup;
  selectedValues: FormArray;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signInForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: '',
      ArrivalTime: '',
      selectedValues: ''
    });
  }}
```

Comment: check this: https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an alternative is to use listbox component and set these options `multiple="multiple" checkbox="checkbox"`

but you can use checkbox component to as group of check box like this

```html
<div [formGroup]="signInForm">

   <p-checkbox [formControl]="signInForm.controls['options']" label="male" value="male">
   </p-checkbox>

   <p-checkbox [formControl]="signInForm.controls['options']" label="female" value="female">
   </p-checkbox>

   <div formArray="selectedValues">
     <div *ngFor="let fc of signInForm.get('selectedValues').controls;let option = index">
        <p-checkbox [formControl]="fc" [label]="option+1" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
     </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

*component*

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.signInForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: '',
      ArrivalTime: '',
      selectedValues: new FormArray([
        this.formBuilder.control(false),
        this.formBuilder.control(false),
        this.formBuilder.control(false),
      ]),
      options:[]
    });
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rzid1c-ent9uw)